# Security with IMG and URL bbcodes

Tags: javascript, regex, bbcode

I'm facing some difficulties when parsing bbcode safely, specifically [img] and [url]. Language is less important, but this is regarding JavaScript.)

1. URLs:
   Not long ago users were able to write [url=#" onclick="alert('test');"]Link[/url] on my site, and when others clicked the link an alert would appear. However, by replacing all double and single quotes with nothing, i.e. removing them, the alert hax did not work any further. My question here is if this is enough security for urls? Or are there any other scenarios I need to be aware of?
2. Images:
   What security features do I need for the img bbcode? Is it enough to remove quotes and check if the end of the url ends with a known image file type, such as .png or .jpg? Or do I need to do more?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Which language do you parse the BBcodes in?

Comment: @SebastianPaaskeTørholm Javascript

Comment: Is there any good reason to roll your own bbcode parsing? If so, you should know that parsing with a regular expression can only get you so far (simple stuff like normalizing a price string, e.g. "$ 15.99" and "15.99" must both return "15.99"). But for anything as far away on the other side of the spectrum as bbcode, you need a real parser, the kind built with tools like lex and yacc. You can learn these in a few days, don't resort to regexps because you think they're easier. You can even write a parser in JS with Jison

Comment: @guillaume I understand that it's a bad idea writing a simple bbcode parser on your own. But since I already has begun and taken myself past several difficult obstacles, (this beging the last one), I hope to still use my own. What I'm asking is really what I need to check for, and then I can write the code myself. For instance, if it's enough to remove all quotes to create safe URLs.

Comment: An interesting article about bbcode and XSS:
http://blog.kotowicz.net/2010/09/bbcode-wont-protect-you-from-xss.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the caveats from my comment, I suggest you just whitelist characters for a URL: a-z, 0-9, &, ., /, ?, :, =, etc. Then replace the `.*?` by your allowed characters :

```
/\[img\]([a-z0-9:&?=\/\.%]+?)\[\/img\]/ig
/\[url\=([a-z0-9:&?=\/\.%]+?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/ig
```

This will cover most cases I think, except international URLs. Quotes are not allowed in this regexp, so no need to escape them. They meant to be expressed as `%22`. Also, this doesn't validate URLs, but only protects from XSS I believe.

Both [url] and [img] take a URL, so this part of the regexp is the same. And you shouldn't check for .png or .jpeg because many images do not have a URL with an explicit extension.

Then the url group in the regexp match will only need to be escaped for HTML.

[Full code](http://jsfiddle.net/2t7Nu/4/):

```
var imgRe = /\[img\]([a-z0-9:&?=\/\.%;]+?)\[\/img\]/ig;
var linkRe = /\[url\=([a-z0-9:&?=\/\.%;]+?)\](.*?)\[\/url\]/ig

$('#convert').click(function() {
    var output = $('#bbcode').val();

    // Escape HTML special characters
    // It's wrong to escape them before converting the bbcode into HTML
    // but I couldn't think of issues
    output = output.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
    output = output.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
    output = output.replace(/"/g, '&quot;');

    // Convert bbcode
    output = output.replace(imgRe, function(str, url) {
        return '<img src="' + url  + '"/>';
    });

    output = output.replace(linkRe, function(str, url, txt) {
        return '<a href="' + url  + '">' + txt + '</a>';
    });

    // print output
    $('#pre').html(output);
});
```